# Want to set parameter in a select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
DECLARE @db AS VARCHAR(20)
SET @db = 'marda_test'

SELECT  t1.[ItemCode]
    ,   t1.[U_FBC]
    ,   t1.[U_FBD]
    ,   t1.[U_FDC]
    ,   t1.[U_FDD]
    ,   t1.[U_CC]
    ,   t1.[U_CD]
    ,   t1.[U_PTC]
    ,   t1.[U_PTD]
    ,   t1.[U_CLRCODE]
    ,   t1.[U_CLRD]
    ,   t1.[U_SC]
    ,   t1.[U_SD]
    ,   t1.[U_SESC]
    ,   t1.[U_SESD]
    ,   t1.[U_FC]
    ,   t1.[U_FD]
    ,   t1.[U_STLCODE]
    ,   t1.[U_STLDESC]
    ,   t1.[U_PPO]
    ,   t1.[U_MG]
    ,   t1.[U_BC]
    ,   t1.[U_BD]
    ,   t1.[U_PC]
    ,   t1.[U_PD]
    ,   t1.[U_SLV]
    ,   t1.[U_COLORC]
    ,   t1.[U_COLORD]
    ,   t1.[ItemCode]
    ,   t1.create_date
FROM oitm_Clone T0, OITM T1
WHERE T0.itemcode = T1.itemcode
    AND @db = '1'
    AND t1.create_date = T0.createdate
    AND t0.U_slv IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Please type in English What exactly "Want to set parameter in a select qry" in your post.

Comment: your question is not clear.
 1. whether you want to set values in a variable ?
 2. or do you want to  writ parametrized query ?

please edit your question apropriately.

Comment: You should avoid ANSI 92 joins since they do not work in SQL Server 2012. See Mike Walsh's blog article on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use [stored procedures](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38682/Overview-of-SQL-Server-Stored-Procedure).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_test1

    @db AS VARCHAR(20)

AS BEGIN

    SELECT *
    FROM OITM T1
    WHERE @db = '1' -- 'marda_test' != '1'
        AND EXISTS(
            SELECT 1 
            FROM oitm_Clone T0
            WHERE T0.itemcode = T1.itemcode
                AND T1.create_date = T0.createdate
                AND T0.U_slv IS NOT NULL
        )

END
GO

EXEC usp_test1 @db = 'marda_test'
```